# REturning variable to parent in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a function

```
exports.myfunction = function(){
connection.open(function (error, client) {
connection.authenticate(user, pass, function (err, val) {
                if (err) {
                return 0;                  
                } else {
                  return 1;

                }
   } 
  }
 }
```

and in another file I want to see the output of this function 0/1. How I can pass this value to the parent function?

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.myfunction = function(callback){
connection.open(function (error, client) {
connection.authenticate(user, pass, function (err, val) {
                if (err) {
                  callback(0);                  
                } else {
                  callback(1);

                }
   } 
  }
 }
```